# Flask mail giving Pickling errors with celery

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery, flask-mail

I trying to use Celery (and rabbitmq) to send emails asynchronously with Flask mail. Initially I had an issue with render_template from flask breaking celery - [Flask-Mail breaks Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036660/flask-mail-breaks-celery) (The celery task would still execute successfully but no emails were being sent). While I was trying to fix that issue (which is still not fixed!) - I stumbled upon another problem. This pickling error which is due to a thread lock. I noticed that the problem started when I changed the way I called the celery task (from delay to apply_async). Since then I tried reverting my changes but I still can't get rid of the error. Any help regarding any one of the issues will be highly appreciated.

The traceback:

```
File "/Users/.../python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py",          line 250, in publish_task
    **kwargs
File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 157, in publish
compression, headers)
File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 233, in _prepare
    body) = encode(body, serializer=serializer)
File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 170, in encode
    payload = encoder(data)
File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 356, in dumps
    return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from flask import render_template
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('tasks', 
            broker = 'amqp://tester:testing@localhost:5672/test_host')

@celery.task(name = "send_async_email")
def send_auth_email(app, nickname, email):
    with app.test_request_context("/"):
        recipients = []
        recipients.append(email)
        subject = render_template("subject.txt")
        msg = Message(subject, recipients = recipients)
        msg.html = render_template("test.html", name = nickname)
        app.mail.send(msg)
```

In the test case I just call:

```
send_auth_email.delay(test_app, nick, email)
```

FYI: The API works perfectly fine if I don't use celery (i.e. synchronously). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `send_auth_email.delay(test_app, nick, email)` all function arguments are being sent to task Queue. To do so, Celery pickles them.

Short answer `test_app`, being flask application, uses some magic and cannot be pickled. See [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/pickle.html#pickle-picklable) for details on what can be pickled, and what not.

One solution is to pass all necessary arguments (in your case it seems that this is only name) to re-instantiate `test_app` in `send_auth_email`.

Comment: It is an instance of the flask application. FYI - I don't have a celeryconfig.py file and a result backend. Should that be an issue?

Comment: no, this will lead further errors, this one clearly do not depends on that. updated answer according to your reply.